# Find destination of a RoutedEvent

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-commands

When I execute a routed command, let's say:

```
ApplicationCommands.Undo.Execute(null, this);
```

WPF does some magic to find the proper `CommandBinding` on which it executes the `ExecutedRoutedEventHandler`.

Is there a way to get a reference to the `CommandBinding` (or at least to the handler) that would be executed?

It would sometimes be nice for debugging to know who is handling a command.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I tried stepping into the .NET framework source for ApplicationCommands.Undo.Exececute(null, this); but I only got "No Source Available". Gonna try and clear my local symbol cache and try again. In the callstack I'm especially interested in PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(object sender = ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check the CommandBinding lists in:

```
       UIElement
       ContentElement 
       UIElement3D
```

ApplicationCommands are checking internally if sender has particular command in CommandBinding. In addition if sender is null then Keyboard.FocusedElement is assigned as sender.